# Как восстановить шаблон админки в Django?

Tags: python, django

[image: Где шаблон админки?]

В Django ведь встроенная админка и ничего не надо настраивать? Вот на компьютере локально всё отображается корректно, а при деплое пропадает оформление. 
Что где нужно посмотреть, дописать?

Comment: Проблема со статикой, не подгружаются css файлы. Какой сервер у вас стоит для статики? nginx?

Comment: @Baterson - делаю на `https://www.pythonanywhere.com/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для деплоя нужно собрать всю статику в одному месте, в `settings.py`  укажите следующее:
`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`
И затем `python manage.py collectstatic`
Эта команда скопирует всю статику проекта в папку, созданную выше. В настройках веб сервера, нужно указать путь до нее.
Настройки сервера для pythonanywhere.com, взятые из официального гайда:

> Finally, set up a static files mapping to get our web servers to serve out your static files for you.
>   Go to the Web tab on the PythonAnywhere dashboard
>   Go to the Static Files section
>   Enter the same URL as STATIC_URL in the url section (typically, /static/)
>   Enter the path from STATIC_ROOT into the path section (the full path, including /home/username/etc)
>   Then hit Reload and test your static file mapping by going to retrieve a known static file.
>   Eg, if you have a file at /home/myusername/myproject/static/css/base.css, go visit http://www.your-domain.com/static/css/base.css

[Гайд с оф. сайта](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/)

Answer (score 0):

На [pythonanywhere.com](http://pythonanywhere.com) (или допустим [heroku](http://heroku.com)), чтобы каждый раз не запускать collectstatic, удобно использовать [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/).

Нужно лишь добавить в settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
  # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```